# How to achieve fast mempool synchronization at startup?

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, mempool, peers, connection

I just started my 'occasional' full-node and I am watching the size of the mempool grow after full block synchronization - `watch -n 3 'bitcoin-cli getrawmempool true |jq "length"'` - it has around 4000 pending transactions. My 'continuous' full-node, however, has around 18000 pending transactions which seem to never become available to my 'ocasional' node.

Looks like that when a node starts up it will receive the new transactions that arrive at the mempool, but the old transactions that had been laying there are never 'synchronized'. How can I synchronize the mempool of a recently launched node with the one of its peers?

I could shut down my other full-node and copy past `mempool.dat` into my other node but this solution is very ugly as I need to shut down a long-running node with many connections.

Comment: Why do you think it matters?

Comment: off the top of my head: fee recommendations with custom code, setting up your electrum server and proving up-to-date intormation, fee bumping transactions made on your mobile wallet through bitcoin core,...

Comment: Fee estimation wouldn’t work if you stuffed the men pool suddenly with old transaction. Electrum servers won’t be started and stopped frequently.

Comment: Fee estimations made by looking at the current size of the mempool would work with old transactions (not bitcoin core recommendations, that's why I wrote 'custom code'). For example you could recommend a fee that is at the top 0.8 vMB of the mempool.

Comment: If you're writing custom code you can surely just not have an "occasional" node.

Comment: Yes, but like I mentioned I have a continuous node and an occasional one. Anyway, I think I found a solution, which is far from ideal but it works. It is to get raw transactions from the mempool through an external API and then broadcast through my node.

Comment: You have a perceived issue with a piece of software you running in a bizarre way given your intentions. The easy solution to your perceived issue is to not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mempoolcp command line utility is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/dev7ba/mempoolcp

Comment: Cheers, I'm surprised someone tackled this 3 years after! Ideally a tool like this would be integrated into bitcoin core, but we all know it's hard to get code merged there.